# How to use varible as search string in egrep

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, grep

I want perform multi-string search from a file using egrep, but use variable to store the search string values. this will help me to programmatically change the search strings. example:-

```
SEARCHSTRING='typesetting industry|printer took|specimen'
cat /tmp/input.file|egrep $SEARCHSTRING > /tmp/output.file
```

input.file content:

```
*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the  
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to  
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,   
but also the leap into electronic*
```

output.file content (expected):

```
*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to  
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,*
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double quote the variable, also use `grep -E` over `egrep`

```
egrep  "$SEARCHSTRING" inputfile
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
```